# My cat threw up once, should I be worried?

Tags: cats, health, diseases, digestion

My cat threw up this morning what looked to be food he recently ate. He is 2 years old, perfectly healthy otherwise as far as I can tell, and hasn't had any other negative signs. Nonetheless, it is the first time he has ever thrown up and I am a bit startled because of this. Should I be taking him into the vet? Should I wait to see if he does it again or develops some other symptoms? Sorry if this is normal or not a big deal, it's just the first time he's ever done so.

Comment: How long have you had your cat?

Comment: God how I _wish_ my cats would only throw up once

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short answer: No.**

Cats do throw up from time to time, and it is normal.

Keep an eye out for:

- more throwing up
- general sluggishness
- less appetite
- lack of defecation

Generally just keep an eye out for more things that point to your cat being sick. If it is just this one throwing up, and he does not do it several times a day, you do not need to go to the vet. If you do notice more symptoms, or he seems off to you, you can also give your vet a call and describe the things you noticed. They will be able to tell you whether you should come by or not.

Answer (score 2):

If he never threw up in his 2 years of life, you're probably not providing him with grass to chew. Although this is not essential for his health and wellbeing, it's still [recommended to offer a cat fresh grass](https://www.petmd.com/cat/care/evr_ct_how-to-grow-cat-grass) for the health benefits and to prevent the cat eating plants that might be toxic.

When cats lick their fur they inevitably swallow hairs, which are very hard to digest. Part of natural and healthy cat behavior is to regurgitate hairballs. [Grass acts like an emetic](https://www.hillspet.com/cat-care/nutrition-feeding/cat-grass-safety-and-information) and helps the process along. So if your cat eats and then vomits grass, it's perfectly healthy.

You can sometimes find little flower pots of cat grass in pet shops, supermarkets or flower shops. There are also cat grass kits available where you get a packet of seeds and grow your own cat grass.